# How to execute script from an Input field on JS?

Tags: javascript

I want to execute script from an editable input field when clicking a button

for example, If you type "*alert("x");*", I want to alert you "x", but also if you type "*for(i=0;i<3;i++){alert(i);}*" I want it to execute it.

How can I achieve this?

> **Edit:** eval() is the only solution? Because I read that it is dangerous:
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#section_5

Comment: Remember to be very careful when doing this.  Be sure you trust your users, as all kinds of malicious javascript could be entered.

Comment: That's true, I just read something when researching about eval() https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#section_5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please note that you're taking input from the user and running it in the context of a script on your site. So the script can do anything that JavaScript running on your browser/domain would have the ability to do (including cookie stealing, XSS, drive-by malware, etc.).

The only thing you can realistically do to mitigate the risks is to not eval() user-provided content. I'd suggest to consider the following alternatives:

1. Use `iframe` as an environment to run user's script:
   http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2006/11/sandbox/
2. Use Caja. It allows websites to safely embed DHTML web applications from third parties, and enables rich interaction between the embedding page and the embedded applications. It uses an object-capability security model to allow for a wide range of flexible security policies.
   http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/

Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Try this one :)
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp

Comment: Try to avoid sending people to w3schools docs if at all possible. Here's some info on eval at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

If you're curious why I say this, this site (though perhaps a little strident) sums it up: http://w3fools.com/

Answer (score 1):

Use the eval() command and it will evaluate and execute the javascript you pass to it.

Answer (score 0):

use eval, like onclick="eval(document.getElementById('your_input'))"